# DBA_HIST_TBSPC_SPACE_USAGE duplicate SNAP_ID

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, data-dictionary

I'm not entirely sure if this is a bug or something that I'm doing wrong, but here goes:

I'm trying to pull historical tablespace information from the [`DBA_HIST_TBSPC_SPACE_USAGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn23456.htm#REFRN23456) data dictionary view.  The documentation says that the `snap_id` value is the *unique* snapshot ID.

However, consider the following query:

```
SELECT snap_id, tablespace_id, rtime, snap_qty
FROM
(
    SELECT
        a.*,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY snap_id, tablespace_id) AS snap_qty
    FROM dba_hist_tbspc_space_usage a
)
WHERE snap_qty > 1
ORDER BY snap_qty DESC, snap_id, tablespace_id, rtime
```

If `snap_id` were unique, I would expect that no `snap_id` would contain a given `tablespace_id` multiple times.  The idea being "one snapshot, one entry per tablespace".

However, that's not the results I get:

```
   SNAP_ID TABLESPACE_ID RTIME                       SNAP_QTY
---------- ------------- ------------------------- ----------
     50874             8 12/04/2014 20:03:41                3
     50874             8 12/04/2014 20:13:41                3
     50874             8 12/04/2014 20:16:40                3

     50295            51 11/28/2014 19:24:12                2
     50295            51 11/28/2014 19:31:09                2

     50494            33 11/30/2014 21:06:49                2
     50494            33 11/30/2014 21:16:41                2

     50609            12 12/02/2014 01:48:26                2
     50609            12 12/02/2014 02:01:01                2

     50643            30 12/02/2014 10:28:54                2
     50643            30 12/02/2014 10:31:30                2

     50684            25 12/02/2014 20:39:33                2
     50684            25 12/02/2014 20:46:07                2

     ...
```

Is this a bug?  Is this expected behavior?  (Should I submit a bug report?)

---

**Edit:** This doesn't seem to be occurring on all of our servers, only a small percent of them.  However, its occurring on both Oracle 12 and Oracle 11.

Comment: Is this a clustered (RAC) database?

Comment: @JonHeller - Nope!  All one one server and only one database instance.

Comment: I looked through a bunch of databases and found the same issue in about 10% of our databases.  This is probably a bug but I can't explain it.

Comment: @JonHeller - I think I've isolated what causes the issue.  The duplicate entries only occur whenever a relatively (as compared to the tablespace size) massive table is created within a tablespace while a snapshot is being created.  I'm still uncertain if it should be considered a bug or not. :\

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.  I couldn't find anything on support.oracle.com.  You'll probably need to create a service request to get an answer to this.  If you do, please post the answer here so it can help someone else.